# Deleted comments to post "Aproximating differential equation in maple"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comment, answers, deletion

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4320942) in the post named Aproximating differential equation in maple. I received beneficial feedback and help but the help comments are not there anymore. Were they deleted or something else. Could someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer was deleted by its author.

Comment: Do you have a link to that question?  We typically get around 600 questions per day...  Looking at likely candidate questions by you ... it seems that you mean the one answer with several comments was deleted.  It was deleted by its author, @Nasser .  You'd have to ask him why he deleted his answer.

Comment: This question belongs on Meta.